# Java Regex to match valid certificate format

Tags: java, regex

What would be the Java Regex equivalent for this regular expression:

```
^(?:(?!-{3,}(?:BEGIN|END) CERTIFICATE)[\s\S])*(-{3,}BEGIN CERTIFICATE(?:(?!-{3,}END CERTIFICATE)[\s\S])*?-{3,}END CERTIFICATE-{3,})(?![\s\S]*?-{3,}BEGIN CERTIFICATE[\s\S]+?-{3,}END CERTIFICATE[\s\S]*?$)
```

The goal of this regex is to validate if a String is a valid SSL Certificate format

Example input

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
section 1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
section 2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Another problem here is that it still does not match the first section, *section 1*, and only matches the *section 2*

Comment: What's the problem with converting that expression to a Java version? Also note that `[\s\S]` is basically anything so you could use `.` instead.

Comment: You may use: `^-{3,}BEGIN CERTIFICATE-{3,}$(?s).*?^-{3,}END CERTIFICATE-{3,}$` in Java. See demo: https://regex101.com/r/3C0loD/1

Comment: @anubhava this regex does not work in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this simpler regex:

```
(?m)^-{3,}BEGIN CERTIFICATE-{3,}$(?s).*?^-{3,}END CERTIFICATE-{3,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3C0loD/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?m)`: Set `MULTILINE` modifier for this regex
- `^-{3,}BEGIN CERTIFICATE-{3,}$`: Match a line with `BEGIN CERTIFICATE`
- `(?s).*?`: Match cert data which may include newlines
- `^-{3,}END CERTIFICATE-{3,}$`: Match a line with `END CERTIFICATE`

For Java use this regex string:

```
final String regex = 
      "(?m)^-{3,}BEGIN CERTIFICATE-{3,}$(?s).*?^-{3,}END CERTIFICATE-{3,}$";
```

Comment: I have tried this and does not work in Java, in PHP it works.

Comment: It works in Java also, Make sure you use `MULTILINE` modifier or use `(?m)` as I have in my example above.